# WL.Logger.Send() its Not callback the WLClientLogReceiver adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have enabled the nativeOptions: {capture: true} in initOptions.js

logger : {enabled: true, level: 'debug', stringify: true, pretty: false,
      tag: {level: false, pkg: true}, whitelist: [], blacklist: [], nativeOptions: {capture: true}}

In my main js file i have the following code.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
// Common initialization code goes here
WL.Logger.setNativeOptions({'capture': true});

var logger = WL.Logger.create({pkg: 'mypackage'});

logger.debug('Hello world - debug');
//[mypackage] Hello world

logger.log('Hello world - log');
//[mypackage] Hello world

logger.info('Hello world - info');
//[mypackage] Hello world

logger.warn('Hello world - warn');
//[mypackage] Hello world

logger.error('Hello world - error');
//[mypackage] Hello world
WL.Logger.send();  }
```

WL.Logger.send() suppose to call my adapter "WLClientLogReceiver". But i am not getting any call for this adapter.

Please let me know, i need to enable any other settings to upload my client side captured log to server.

```
 function log(deviceInfo, logMessages) {
 return true;}

<procedure name="log" securityTest="wl_unprotected" audit="true" />
```

Comment: Do you have logcat or xcode console logs?  What about server logs?  What version of WL client + server?  What is the contents of your WLClientLogReceiver.xml descriptor file?  What is the procedure you implemented in the adapter?

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  You have no indication in the server log file (messages.log on liberty) that the adapter was called?  logcat or xcode console has no indication of attempt to send?

Comment: Worklight Studio Version 6.1 FixPack 1.

Comment: What is location of server log in Worklight Studio, Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i thought it will have some indication in the Worklight Console Log or Xcode / log cat console. Its available in the messages.log. Its working find and the logs has been uploaded to the server.

Comment: Overlapped answers again.  YW.  I'll repost my comment as an answer, and you would please mark it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logger : {enabled: true, level: 'debug', stringify: true, pretty: false, tag: {level: false, pkg: true}, whitelist: [], blacklist: [], nativeOptions: {capture: true}}

You have enabled the native capture as true in initOptions.js so no need to set it again.

You can log using your package that will help you in filtering the messages based on the package in your WLClientLogReceiver adapter.

```
var myloggerObject = WL.Logger.create({pkg: 'mypackage'});
myloggerObject.debug("Hello world");
```

you can specify your level in your js file to be logged in client device.

```
In the adapter you will get the log messages as an json array.
```

function log(deviceInfo, logMessages) {

/* The adapter can choose to process the parameters, 
     for example to forward them to a backend server for 
     safekeeping and further analysis.

```
 The deviceInfo object may look like this:
 {
   "appName":       "wlapp",
   "appVersion":    "1.0",
   "deviceId":      "66eed0c9-ecf7-355f-914a-3cedac70ebcc",
   "model":         "Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280",
   "systemName":    "Android",
   "systemVersion": "4.2.2",
   "os.arch":       "i686",           // Android only
   "os.version":    "3.4.0-qemu+"     // Android only
  }
  The logMessages parameter is a JSON array 
  that contains JSON object elements, and might look like this:

    [{
      "timestamp"    : "17-02-2013 13:54:23:745",  // "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:S"
      "level"        : "ERROR",                    // ERROR||WARN||INFO||LOG|| DEBUG
      "package"      : "your_tag",                 // typically a class name
      "msg"          : "the message",              // a helpful log message
      "threadid"     : 42,                         // (Android only)the current thread
      "metadata"     : { "$src" : "js" }           // metadata placed on the log call
    }]
```

*/

//sample log and filtering method

```
var logs= [{
      "timestamp"    : "17-02-2013 13:54:23:745",  // "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:S"
      "level"        : "ERROR",                    // ERROR||WARN||INFO||LOG|| DEBUG
      "package"      : "your_tag",                 // typically a class name
      "msg"          : "the message",              // a helpful log message
      "threadid"     : 42,                         // (Android only)the current thread
      "metadata"     : { "$src" : "js" }           // metadata placed on the log call
    },
    {
      "timestamp"    : "17-02-2013 13:54:23:745",  // "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:S"
      "level"        : "ERROR",                    // ERROR||WARN||INFO||LOG|| DEBUG
      "package"      : "mypackage",                 // typically a class name
      "msg"          : "my package message",              // a helpful log message
      "threadid"     : 42,                         // (Android only)the current thread
      "metadata"     : { "$src" : "js" }           // metadata placed on the log call
    }
  ];
 var filteredLogs = logs.filter(function(log){
           if(log.package == mypackage) //comparing the package and returns the object
                { return log; }   
});

WL.Logger.error(filteredLogs);// This is send only the filtered array to your server

 }
```

If you log using metadata such as filename along with the debug message you will get those in the array in metadata attribute.

It is suggested to stringify and parse the object to avoid errors before parsing the device logs in the adapter.

```
var logs = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(logs));
var filteredLogs = logs.filter ...
```

Hope this will work for you.

Make sure you test it using the device.

Answer (score 2):

The `send` function is not attached to the `LogInstance` prototype, which is what you're using when you use a logger instance created with `WL.Logger.create()`.  Please call

```
WL.Logger.send();
```

instead.

**(Above was posted prior to OP's edit.)**

Since `setNativeOptions` is an asynchronous call (it calls down through a Cordova plugin), it is possible it has not successfully turned capture on prior to completion of the subsequent `logger` calls.  So at the time of the call to `WL.Logger.send();` nothing has been collected yet.

Do this:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    // Common initialization code goes here
    WL.Logger.setNativeOptions({'capture': true})

    .then(function() {

        var logger = WL.Logger.create({pkg: 'mypackage'});

        logger.debug('Hello world - debug');
        //[mypackage] Hello world

        logger.log('Hello world - log');
        //[mypackage] Hello world

        logger.info('Hello world - info');
        //[mypackage] Hello world

        logger.warn('Hello world - warn');
        //[mypackage] Hello world

        logger.error('Hello world - error');
        //[mypackage] Hello world

        WL.Logger.send();

    });
}
```

Comment: Well now the edit makes my answer sound dumb.  :)  Your original indicated you were calling `logger.send();`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check the server-side logs.  The `audit="true"` in the adapter's descriptor file will print the parameters passed to the adapter inline in the server logs (messages.log on WebSphere Liberty).

Comment: Thanks, What is location of log file if its installed in WAS WebSphere 8.5 full profile.